# generate webservice client from HTTPS wsdl using java in Axis2 Runtime

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, java-7, wsdl2java, wsimport

I am trying to generate (SOAP) Web-service client classes using WSDL (https://dpdmsdmmk1.fmr.com:12210/cmis/services/RepositoryService?wsdl) which is having HTTPS in the url.

Paste_WSDL_Below: https://dpdmsdmmk1.fmr.com:12210/cmis/services/RepositoryService?wsdl

Trail 1: From command Prompt wsimport -d C:\Users\A550857\Desktop\Jay
-extension -keep -p com.gatewayedi.ws -XadditionalHeaders Paste_WSDL_Below

Response on command prompt:

parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: su n.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid c ertification path to requested target

Failed to read the WSDL document: Paste_WSDL_Below, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the documen t could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

Failed to parse the WSDL.

Trail 2: From command Prompt

{C:\Users\A550857\Desktop\Jay\Softs\axis2-1.6.2\bin>wsdl2java.bat -uri Paste_WSDL_Below

Response on command prompt:

Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Users\A550857\Desktop\Jay\Softs\axis2-1.6.2 Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.i18n.Project ResourceBundle). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException : Error parsing WSDL
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerat ionEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.Validator Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPath BuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker. java:1337)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.jav a:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:998)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl. java:1294)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321 )
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305 )
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java: 523)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon nection.java:1296)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468 )
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Htt psURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerat ionEngine.java:99)
        ... 2 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.jav a:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.j ava:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerIm pl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustMan agerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker. java:1319)
        ... 15 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to  find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCert PathBuilder.java:196)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 21 more }

Environment i am using:  Axis2-1.6.2,  Java7, WSDL:Paste_WSDL_Below

Pl suggest on this. i am able to view the WSDL in browser with proper content.

Comment: Any suggestions, Pl help me fast

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Import the server certificate to your jdk's truststore
(sample: http://www.coderanch.com/t/134619/Security/JDK-trust-Certificate). You're getting the exception because your JDK is not trusting the server certificate.

2) Download the wsdl to your local drive including the referenced xsd-files if present and run wsimport towards the local wsdl and not the wsdl from the https-page.

I'd do the second approach, as it is much simpler.

Comment: i followed step 1 added the certificate but am still getting an error `java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching XXXXX.co.ke found.` The issue with step two is that, the generated java code contains file url to the downloaded check.wsdl instead of website url.

Comment: Actually step one worked. i was passing `XXXXX.co.ke` instead of `www.XXXX.co.ke`